# Fragment back stack clearing Issue

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-alertdialog, fragment-backstack

I am working with `fragments` and the navigation flow like

```
 Fragment A -> Fragment B -> Fragment C -> Fragment D
```

Form `fragment` D I need to navigate to `fragment` A by clearing back stack but the problem is in `onCreateView()` method of `fragment` C I am showing one dialog

When I am navigating from D to A by clearing the back stack Over `fragment` A same pop-up appears which was shown in on fragment C

below is the code  I am using to clear the stack

```
FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();

for (int i = 0; i < fm.getBackStackEntryCount(); ++i) {
     fm.popBackStack();
   }
```

Comment: When you move from Frag C to Frag D, you are using replace, correct?

Comment: Yes, I am using replace

Comment: Solution in answer bellow., let me know if it worked. Happy coding :)

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: Instead of using replace use add (when you want to call onCreateView call each time on popUpBackStack all replace, when you dont call add method)

Comment: Yes using add method it worked...!! Thank You :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you have lies in the way you are dealing with the fragments lifecycle. You want Fragment C to do `onCreateView` only once (to show the popup), but `onCreateView` get's called every time the View is created (e.g, every time you call remove on a fragment(replace works pretty much the same, remove + add) and then add it back from backstack with popbackstack).

For your problems there are two solutions:

Cleaner one: instead of showing your popup from `onCreateView`, call it from `onCreate` in Fragment C. With this you will guarantee that it only get's called when the fragment instance is created.

Not so clean: Instead of using `replace` between Fragment C and D transaction, call `add`, this way when you pop the backstack in Fragment D, Fragment C `onCreateView` won't be called because the View was never destroyed (never called remove/replace upon).

Comment: Using add method works fine for me but i didn't get why you said that its not so clean

Comment: I didn't say it wasn't clean, I said it wasn't so clean. To use Fragment replacement gives you a full control of what happens in your container, which does not happen as easily with add. It still a good approach.